# Why doesn't my 12-column markup fit the md resolution?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had nice 12-column grid with `column-md-*` classes. Then I decided to make the page look better at the `sm` size, so I added some `column-sm-*` classes to my divs.

After that the whole thing behaves strangely in `md` and `lg` resolutions.

Here's the code: http://bootply.com/105536

There are two rows, one is "after adding sm classes" and the second one is "before", and it looks ok at medium and large.

Why did the `sm` classes ruin the `md` grid?

Comment: What exactly is it that you need? Can you post a pic of the layout?

Comment: Also, why are you using the `offset` class?

Comment: @Ranveer I need it to behave like the first row in `sm` and like the second row in medium and large.

Comment: @Skelly I used it to make the two inputs have the same size as textarea.
But that's where the bug is. That offset propagated to `md` and `lg`. So I just added `column-md-offset-0` and everything became allright. 
http://bootply.com/105540

Answer (score 1):

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

so you need to override  `col-sm-offset-1`, like

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0">
```